# Delphi newbie error (Missing operator or semicolon)

Tags: delphi

I'm new to Delphi Programming and I really can't figure out why these lines of code aren't working. Any help will be appreciated.

Code:

```
begin
  rNum := StrToFloat(Edit6.Text);
  edtRound.Text := IntToStr(round(rNum));
  edtSqr.Text := FloatToStrF(sqr(rNum), ffFixed, 8, 3);
  edtSqrt.Text := FloatToStrF(sqrt(rNum), ffFixed, 8, 3);
  edtFrac.Text := FloatToStr(Frac(rNum));
  edtTrunc.Text := IntToStr(trunc(rNum));
  edtFrac.Text := FloatToStr(frac(rNum));
end;
```

The error I get is:

> Error: Missing operator or semicolon

Comment: There is no syntax error in your snippet.

Comment: Check the line before those three. If the line before that is missing a `;`, it cannot be detected on that line, because the `;` *could* be placed on a new line all by itself. It's only when the compiler sees `edtFrac` that it can tell that there really is no `;`.

Comment: It's giving me that error for each of those 3 lines. If I comment out the one line it will give me that error for the next line. If I move either 3 of those lines to the top of my code I still get that problem. I added the full code to the original post.

Comment: Show a complete program. The error comes from other code.

Comment: Btw, despite your edit, your q still says "these 3 lines of code".  Maybe the down-votes would reduce if you fixed it a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This program compiles successfully:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

procedure Foo;
var
  Text: string;
  rNum: Double;
begin
  rNum := StrToFloat(Text);
  Text := IntToStr(round(rNum));
  Text := FloatToStrF(sqr(rNum), ffFixed, 8, 3);
  Text := FloatToStrF(sqrt(rNum), ffFixed, 8, 3);
  Text := FloatToStr(Frac(rNum));
  Text := IntToStr(trunc(rNum));
  Text := FloatToStr(Frac(rNum));
end;

begin
end.
```

I've changed your code in order to make a simple program that can be posted easily.

What this shows you is that your problem does not lie in the code that you showed. The problem is somewhere else. Working out what that specific problem is should not be the main lesson for you to learn. The main lesson should be how to simplify a problem and so diagnose it clearly.

What you should do is start from your current code and start stripping things out. When you strip out something that makes a difference to behaviour, you have learnt something. Put that thing back and work out why removing it changed behaviour. At that point you should have an explanation.

Now consider this program:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

const
  Frac: Double = 0.0;

procedure Foo;
var
  Text: string;
  rNum: Double;
begin
  rNum := StrToFloat(Text);
  Text := IntToStr(round(rNum));
  Text := FloatToStrF(sqr(rNum), ffFixed, 8, 3);
  Text := FloatToStrF(sqrt(rNum), ffFixed, 8, 3);
  Text := FloatToStr(Frac(rNum));
  Text := IntToStr(trunc(rNum));
  Text := FloatToStr(Frac(rNum));
end;    
begin
end.
```

It fails to compile on the line that refers to `Frac` and the compiler reports this error:

> [dcc32 Error]: E2066 Missing operator or semicolon

So, you presumably have a similar problem. You will have defined an extra symbol that is hiding one the symbol that you are intending to refer to.

Comment: Not me gov.  Mind you, I've seen a few d/vs on Delphi answers recently where the only explanation seems to be that the voter is expressing disapproval of answering a not-v-good q.